# Save image from PictureBox (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, picturebox

I have this simple windows form application that enable user to view image and save it to their own device. Here is coding that I currently use to save image from PictureBox.

```
Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim SaveFileAs As New SaveFileDialog
    SaveFileAs.Title = "Save File As"
    SaveFileAs.FileName = "*.jpg"
    SaveFileAs.Filter = "Jpeg |*.jpg"
    If SaveFileAs.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileAs.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that, it opening dialog two times before the image can be saved. I have tried this coding as well :

```
Dim SaveFileAs As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
PictureBox1.Image.Save(SaveFileAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

This coding opening dialog once and can directly save the image, but the problem is, the image is not displayed when viewed from folder where it saved.

Is there any better way to save a picture? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove `SaveFileAs.FileName = "*.jpg"` from your first code?

Comment: Still the same result. The `SaveFileAs.FileName = "*.jpg"` doesn't give any effect on the dialog because it's only a **name** for the picture that will be saved.

Comment: I believe that the problem occurred in `if...end if` statement but I don't have any idea on how to fix it.

Comment: `FileName` is the **name _and_ path** of the file. I know it shouldn't do anything, but since you said it shows once in your second code (where I don't see any `.ShowDialog()`) I thought it could be that.

Comment: Anyway, your If-statement should work. Try declaring the dialog once at class-level, and subscribe to it's `FileOk` event. By the way, which version of the .NET Framework have you targeted?

Comment: I will try it out. I'm using the .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: It's working now! Yay! Thank you so much @VisualVincent :D